# The constructor AdRequest() is not visible

Tags: java, android, admob

I'm trying to put some ad in my Android app, but I've a problem...

```
package com.dotgears.flappybird;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.google.ads.*;


public class BannerSample extends Activity {
      private AdView adView;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "...");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        // Add the adView to it
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
    }
```

I followed the Google dev's istructions but on the line `adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());` Eclipse says:

> The constructor AdRequest() is not visible

Why isn't it visible?
I searched everywhere but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you the creator of flappy bird? If not, what the hell are you doing.

Comment: Hahhaa yeah. Are you using google play game services? Using that with AdMob causes problems

Comment: Kayaman ahahah nope I just lost a bet xD
@HamzahMalik I'm not using GPlay game services. Actually I have only this activity and the Main one (that is blank).

Comment: What libraries have you included in your project. It looks like you have included Google play Services but are attempting to use classes from the old Admob package

Answer (score 3):

Do it in this way

```
AdRequest adreq=new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     adview.loadAd(adreq);
```

and it will work.
 also import it by using

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
```

and it will start working

Answer (score 3):

simply use the following import

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
```

also add the lib of google play services

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem. that was because i was using Google Play services and Google Admob together i just removed google play services library and it worked!